LazyRow non-observable firstVisibleItemIndex?
I'm tring to find max() on a subset of initial data before laying out an item of a LazyRow. The subset will consist of only visible items and I need to read firstVisibleItemIndex without triggering recompositions.
Related code:
@Composable
fun TestComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

    val dataList = mutableListOf<Int>().apply {
        repeat(100) {
            add((0..100).random())
        }
    }
    val windowSize = 4

    LazyRow(
        state = scrollState
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(dataList,
            key = { index, item -> index }) { index, item ->
            val firstIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex // <-- Observable and causes recompositions

            val endIndex = firstIndex + windowSize
            val lastIndex = if (endIndex > dataList.size - 1)
                dataList.size - 1
            else
                endIndex
            val max = dataList
                .subList(firstIndex, lastIndex) // For simplicity let it be sublist here
                .max()

            Text(max.toString())
        }
    }
}

How should I access firstVisibleItemIndex value without recompositions?

"I need to read firstVisibleItemIndex without triggering recompositions.": But whenever the user scrolls the list, firstVisibleItemIndex changes. So you need the recomposition, otherwise the calculation's result isn't up-to-date anymore. Can you better explain how you want to achieve this without recomposition? That's what it is for, after all.

@tyg, wouldn't it work if it was something like
var firstVisibleItemIndex = 0 instead of var firstVisibleItemIndex by mutableIntStateOf(0)?
Maybe observable index is OK but I was confused with a note in sources: Note that this property is observable and if you use it in the composable function it will be recomposed on every change causing potential performance issues.

That value changes a lot (whenever the user scrolls so that a new item is at the first position in the list). It is a MutableState so that you can react to its current value (otherwise it would be pretty useless). I haven't understood why you need it (the calculation doesn't make any sense for me), but if you want to calculate anything that is based on the first visible index, you obviously have to repeat the calculation whenever that index changes. That happens automatically because it is a MutableState and Compose schedules a recomposition whenever it changes...

... Therefore I would assume that you want the recomposition to happen. Nevertheless, your question is about how to avoid the recomposition. Which seems rather strange. Hence my request for clarification: Can you explain what you actually want to achieve? Everything seems to already work as it should.

To access firstVisibleItemIndex without triggering recompositions in a LazyRow, you can use LaunchedEffect with a snapshotFlow. This approach observes changes to scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex and updates a MutableState or performs computations as needed without directly tying the observable value to composable recompositions.
Here’s how you can implement it:
@Composable
fun TestComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

    val dataList = mutableListOf<Int>().apply {
        repeat(100) {
            add((0..100).random())
        }
    }
    val windowSize = 4

    // State to hold the max value
    val maxForVisibleItems = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // Launch a side effect to observe firstVisibleItemIndex changes
    LaunchedEffect(scrollState) {
        snapshotFlow { scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
            .collect { firstIndex ->
                val endIndex = firstIndex + windowSize
                val lastIndex = if (endIndex > dataList.size - 1) dataList.size - 1 else endIndex
                maxForVisibleItems.value = dataList.subList(firstIndex, lastIndex).maxOrNull() ?: 0
            }
    }

    LazyRow(
        state = scrollState
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(dataList, key = { index, item -> index }) { index, item ->
            Text(maxForVisibleItems.value.toString()) // Use the precomputed max value
        }
    }
}

Explanation:
Using snapshotFlow:
The snapshotFlow observes changes to the firstVisibleItemIndex without causing recompositions.
It captures the value of scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex in a coroutine.
Updating State in LaunchedEffect:
Inside the collect block, compute the max for the visible items and update maxForVisibleItems.
This ensures that the computation runs only when firstVisibleItemIndex changes.
Displaying the Max Value:
The Text composable uses the precomputed value from maxForVisibleItems, avoiding unnecessary recompositions due to direct observation of firstVisibleItemIndex.
Handling Edge Cases:
If the list is empty or the computation yields no results, maxOrNull ensures safe handling with a default fallback.
